# Looping over lineEdits in different tabs of the qt-dialog

Tags: python, dictionary, pyqt, qgis, pyqgis

I'm writing a QGIS plug-in to modify the attributes of a shapefile's features based on categories (the category of each feature is saved in one of the attributes). The relevant part of my Qt-dialog is grouped into tabs, where each tab includes the factors that are to be used in the calculations for a specified category (e.g. all features of category IV are modified using the information in tab IV). Example of what that looks like in QtDesigner:
[image: Snap from QtDesigner]

Since the number of categories is quite high I would like to automate the corresponding script, that is, I want to iterate over the tabs and execute the same operations automatically (for example calculating and displaying the rowsums in the "totale" fields). I think there should be a way to do this using dictionaries but I'm having troubles.

To access the values of the fields (in tab/category IV) I use commands like this:

> self.dlg.lineEdit_carPeakHour_IV.text()

From what I understand, to iteratively access all of the lineEdit_carPeakHour_i (i being the iterator over the categories/tabs) I would need to somehow manage to include the iterator into the variable name itself. My goal is to have a dict with the categories as keys ('I', II', 'III', 'IV', ...) and the expression (lineEdit_carPeakHour_I, lineEdit_carPeakHour_II, lineEdit_carPeakHour_III, lineEdit_carPeakHour_IV, ...) as values. Is that at all possible or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Before suggesting anything, are those tabs all the same? Because if that's the case, creating *every single one* in designer is not very effective, as you should create just one of them as a "prototype" that you can use as a class, and dynamically add the tabs by code. This would make attribute naming much more consistent and simple, and solve your issue at the same time, since you only need to call the same function for every instance. Besides that, I've to say, using roman numbering, especially for object namings, is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Yes, they're all equal in structure and content. I figured that it might not be very advisable. Unfortunately this is the first qgis-plug-in I create and my first work with qt as well so something like this was to be expected.

Comment: Follow-up question: How do I go about converting my first tab (advise on roman numerals noted) to a prototype, that I can then add as new tabs in the code? So far I developed all of my UI and most of the used signals in QtDesigner and only the calculations, the adding and modification of new attributes and a handful of signals are developed in code.

Comment: You must create a basic Widget ("Form") in Designer that will have all the contents that you're repeating in each tab (you can select all the elements in the first tab and drag them on the new form). Obviously, there will be *no* "tab" in that form. Then, you remove **all** tabs from the QTabWidget in your main interface and rebuild everything (if you used pyuic). On the python side, you must have two classes: one for the "page", the other the main window, which will create all tabs using the page class, add them with `addTab()`, and possibly connect all signals to whatever you need.

Comment: I suggest you to start with a small test: just create a basic form, a couple of line edits and buttons, and then a main window with the empty qtabwidget, and try developing the concept with this small scale, so that you better understand how it works how you could implement it for your project. Remember that when a new QTabWidget is added, it always has two tabs, so you must remove all of them for this kind of implementation (right click on tab, "Page x of y" menu, "Delete").

Comment: so first I tried storing the content of the tab in a QWidget and moving said QWidget to the scratchpad. that worked but didn't provide me with any solutions on how to go on. next I put the content of the tab in a form called CategoryWidget.ui - here the problem becomes that if I build the .py file, it doesn't contain a class "CategoryWidget" but only the class UiForm, which I can't put in my (push-button-generated) tabs. Any further tips?

Comment: The name of the ui file is completely irrelevant for the class. If it's called `UiForm`, then create a subclass of both QWidget *and* UiForm: `class CategoryWidget(QWidget, UiForm)`, and call `self.setupUi(self)` in the `__init__`. Then use `addTab()` with instances of that class: `newPage = CategoryWidget()` `self.tabWidget.addTab(newPage, 'IV')`.

Comment: thanks for the quick and helpful reply! your proposal makes sense. I do, however, get an error "Cannot create consistent method ordering" when I try to make a subclass of both QWidget and UiForm. Could UiForm itself be a subclass of QWidget? If I try to initialize it as  `class CategoryWidget(Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        self.setupUi(self)` I run into the issue that the initialization is faulty. Can you recommend an example of what this might look like?

Comment: That should not happen. Is `UiForm` the class in the file generated by pyuic? That "form class" should *not* inherit from QWidget, it's just a basic python object and should **never** be modified by hand, but only imported in your main script so that it can be inherited along with QWidget. See the multiple inheritance method explanation in the guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: Just to keep you updated, I gave up on this approach and solve it by making the user import a csv where each category is a row (instead of having them enter the information in the dialog with each category being a tab). The obstacle was too big for me. Thank you for your support and your time.